# Workflow Rule Formula to Fire only when a Date Value is changed from Blank to Populated

Tags: formula

I have a field called "Form_1A_Complete_A__c" and I want to have the WFR fire when the date goes from blank to populated. I don't want the rule to keep firing after the value is set. What's the best way to incorporate ISCHANGED() into a date field?

NOT(

ISBLANK(Form_1A_Complete_A__c)

Comment: Just use the `created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria` together with `NOT(ISBLANK(Form_1A_Complete_A__c))`. If you don't want to apply when the record is created, add the NOT(ISNEW()) to the conditions

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the best approach here would probably be to set your wofklow rule evaluation to happen when the record is `created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria`.